# Plot bar chart of counts of where dummy variables == 1 AND a separate variable in the Series == 1

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas DataFrame with dummy variables for age ranges, specifically '<35', '35-44', '45-54', '55-64', and '65+'. I have another dummy variable that represents if someone's hair has gone grey yet, 'grey?'.

I would like to plot a bar chart of how many people have grey hair per 1,000 people by age group. So basically, for each age group dummy where dummy == 1, (count of grey dummy == 1 / people where age group dummy == 1) * 1000, and plot as bar chart.

What is the best way to do this?

EDIT:
I ended up figuring out *a* way to do it, but it might not be *the best* way to do it.

```
counts_list = []

for col in ['<35', '35-44', '45-54', '55-64', '65+']:
    counts_df = df.groupby(col)['grey?'].value_counts()
    try:
        counts_list.append(counts_df[1][1] / (counts_df[1][1] + counts_df[1][0]) * 1000)
    except:
        counts_list.append(0)
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rc("font", size=14)
y_pos = np.arange(len(['<35', '35-44', '45-54', '55-64', '65+']))

plt.bar(y_pos, counts_list, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, ['<35', '35-44', '45-54', '55-64', '65+'])
plt.ylabel('Grey/1k')
plt.title('Grey by Age')

plt.show()
```

Is there a more idiomatic/pythonic way to do this same thing?

Comment: Please post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what code you have attempted.

Comment: @Brendan I posted the code I wrote that does what I want, but I'm just not certain if there isn't a more idiomatic way to do it

Comment: @rosstripi Your sample code has `counts_df = df.groupby(col)['grey?'].value_counts()` -- what data is going into `df`? Your question should ideally include a block of code anyone can simply copy, paste, and run to replicate your results. Use `df.to_dict()` to output your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out *a* way to do it, but it might not be *the best* way to do it.

```
counts_list = []

for col in ['<35', '35-44', '45-54', '55-64', '65+']:
    counts_df = df.groupby(col)['grey?'].value_counts()
    try:
        counts_list.append(counts_df[1][1] / (counts_df[1][1] + counts_df[1][0]) * 1000)
    except:
        counts_list.append(0)
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rc("font", size=14)
y_pos = np.arange(len(['<35', '35-44', '45-54', '55-64', '65+']))

plt.bar(y_pos, counts_list, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, ['<35', '35-44', '45-54', '55-64', '65+'])
plt.ylabel('Grey/1k')
plt.title('Grey by Age')

plt.show()
```